# How do i manually write /etc/fstab?

Tags: data-recovery, fstab

I accidently deleted my /etc/ directory. Here is my disk with installation -

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5401B3C5-4DA4-4F2D-BB2B-F1845E8E8E4F

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    2050047     999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 1953523711 1951473664 930.5G Linux filesystem

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Jun  9 03:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 160 Jun  9 03:07 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:08 64490475-1baf-4a81-a7be- 87f617f51228 -> ../../sda2                        
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:08 D378-4726 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:18 db611ff4-b7e6-41ad-935b-d70ee56a30ac -> ../../sda3

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:18 dc7811ca-4 c11-4547-9971-49ef2409989f -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:08 6895-5744 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun  9 03:18 a4774c86-924b-425f-a6ef-3cba2d2cb24a -> ../../dm-2
```

i dont want to reinstall. I have a live USB. I want to manually write the /etc/fstab file to get my system to boot atleast. What should be the entries?

Comment: There's a whole lot of stuff in /etc besides fstab.  If you deleted /etc from the GUI it could be sitting in your trash can waiting to be restored.  If there is a backup anywhere, this thread may help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/814811/how-to-restore-fstab-file

Comment: Could you please mount all these drives, list the content of their root directory and [edit] your question to include the listings? We also need the output of `sudo lsblk -f`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/320914/423684) using extundelete. As said in the comments fstab alone won't bring your system back!

Try to recover the whole folder if it's not too late. **Important: This will only work if you don't mess around with it now until you recovered!**

If it does not work try to at least get you data out there and reinstall your system.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!